# It is different to Javascript, getting JSON as "text/html" and as "file"?

Tags: javascript, json

In JavaScript I get JSON data. The service sends me back JSON data in a file (HTTP Header - `file`), a second service sends me back data as text in browser (HTTP Header type - `text/html`).

I need to parse this data in JavaScript (ExtJS).

It is different to Javascript, getting  JSON as `text/html` and as `file`?

I know that with  `text/html` - all works fine, but will it work with other HTTP Header type (that retrieves file that contains JSON)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your response content-type is `text/html` you should be fine, as long as you parse the response with something like `JSON.parse` (see [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for older browsers that don't have this natively) it should be fine.

In fact, if you're loading your response from an iframe - [IE will prompt you to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340192/ie-wants-to-download-returned-json-from-django) if your response is `application/json`. This should only be an issue if you're attempting a file upload without refreshing the page though.

To be honest I've never tried with other header types. I would imagine `text/plain` could work, however you may run into the IE iframe download issue above.

My recommendation would be to use `application/json` if you can, however failing this `text/html` should suffice

Answer (score 1):

It [should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) `application/json`.

If it is anything else, it might break clients that try to detect the result type automatically. But if a client expects JSON, they will probably ignore the header anyway.